# how to use svn dcommit for svn-all-fast-export Qt script

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have imported the subversion repository to Git repository by [svn-all-fast-export](http://gitorious.org/svn2git).

However, after imported the project, I don't know the way to keep maintain reposirory synchonize with the SVN which still have some users using.

I cannot find the way to use `git svn fetch` or `git svn dcommit` after done the imported.

Comment: Do you mean SVN <-> Git synchronization on the server? Synchronization between local Git and remote SVN?

Comment: Yes. Previously, I use SVN2Git, so, I still using `git svn fetch` and `git svn dcommit` because the main repository still in the SVN, not Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN2Git is for 1-shot conversion. For SVN <-> Git synchronization on the server, you need to setup any SVN-Git gateway like [SubGit](http://subgit.com). To do that run on the server

```
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repository
```

And setup Git access to the Git repository created at `path/to/svn/repository/.git`

Alternatively you can use [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) locally and just SVN on the server. To start working with SVN repository, clone it first:

```
$ git svn clone <URL> --stdlayout path/for/local/git/repository
```

to fetch changes from SVN run `git svn rebase` and to push current branch --- `git svn dcommit`

Answer (score 0):

`svn-all-fast-export` is incremental, if you're careful not to delete the marks and logs files.  So, you can periodically run it on your SVN repository, and it will update the git repositories.